# How to trigger ripple effect on Switch click for its container

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to replicate the effect used in the Settings app for Android 12, where the ripple effect is automatically triggered whenever an option is clicked (including the `Switch` itself). However, in my app, the ripple effect does not happen at all, only the `Switch` animates.

```
@Composable
fun ComposableSettingSimpleMode() {
    val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable(onClick = {})) {
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.simple_mode))
        Switch(checked = isChecked.value, onCheckedChange = {
            isChecked.value = it
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `toggleable` modifier:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableSettingSimpleMode() {
    val isChecked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .toggleable(
                value = isChecked.value,
                onValueChange = { isChecked.value = it },
            ),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello")
        Switch(checked = isChecked.value, onCheckedChange = null)
    }
}
```

The important points are:

- The entire row is made "toggleable" (i.e. whatever you want to have the ripple effect on);
- The `toggleable` modifier requires a `value`, which should have the same value as the switch, and an `onValueChange`, which should perform the actual switch state change (which currently is on the Switch's `onCheckedChange`);
- The Switch's `onCheckedChange` should be set to `null`, otherwise it will "steal" the click from the row when the Switch is clicked, and the row won't ripple;

Answer (score 2):

This is where you pass in your own `InteractionSource`

```kotlin
    var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = LocalIndication.current,
                onClick = {
                    isChecked = !isChecked
                }
            )
    ) {
        Text(text = "Dummy Text", Modifier.weight(1f))
        Switch(
            checked = isChecked,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            onCheckedChange = {
                isChecked = it
            })
    }
```